# Why is one face in my mesh not being rounded by the subsurf modifier?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Why is one rectangle being the same fixed point and not being rounded?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Subdivision 6 is really too much. Stay under 4 if possible (3 should be enough)

Comment: Remove doubles if you already didn't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem **could be** that you have duplicated vertices.

Try to select the overlapping vertices in your red circle (the one you draw in the screenshot) and merge them <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> in *Edit Mode*. Do it for all the 4 areas that generate the rectangle.